# What controls are these in my screenshot?

Tags: android

I wonder, what's the names of these controls? Are these

- list view
- dialog (what kind of dialog exactly? Is it from the standard android library?)
- In the dialog: radio box group
- How to create a "go back arrow"?

?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are looking at a `PreferenceActivity`
2. You can get the BACK arrow using this:

   ```
   getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   ```
3. Concerning the second image : that's a custom dialog with radio buttons.

Comment: that's just an example, I don't want to use the that Activity, I want to know the controls it consists of.

Comment: Also, shouldn't I use "preferencefragment" instead?

Comment: depends on how are you intending to use it.

Comment: PreferenceActivity, AlertDialog, RadioButton.

Comment: and the activity itself -- listView?

Comment: No, no no. This activity is a 'PreferenceActivity', not a 'ListActivity'. If you want the list, you gonna have to add it yourself to its layout.

Comment: I'm not asking about what kind of activity it is. I'm asking about the controls it contains!

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's a ListView or a RecyclerView.

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is `PreferenceActivity` setting
2. It is dialog box having Radio Group.
3. To create a go back arrow:

   ```
   getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   ```

Comment: that's just an example, I don't want to use the that Activity, I want to know the controls it consists of. Also, shouldn't I use "preferencefragment" instead?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example on how to make a dialog like the one you showed :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Context context = this;

        String items[] = {"For all calls", "Only for SIP calls"};
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setSingleChoiceItems(items, 1, null)
                .setTitle("Use SIP calling")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        int selectedPosition = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();
                        // Do something useful withe the position of the selected radio button
                        Toast.makeText(context, "The element " + selectedPosition + " was selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
}
```

If you want a **Material Design** dialog for pre-Lollipop versions, you can use this library :
https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs (see **Single Choice List Dialogs**)